# What is the significance of the target argument in glBufferData

Tags: opengl

When creating a Buffer and setting its data, it is required to bind it first to a `target` and then populate the buffer bound to that `target` with some data:

```
GLenum target = GL_ARRAY_BUFFER;
glGenBuffers(1, &bufferId);
glBindBuffer(target, bufferId);
glBufferData(target, m_capacity*sizeof(value_type), m_data, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(target, 0);
```

But to my understanding it does not really matter if I a buffer that was populated on the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` target is later used on e.g. the `GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER` target. But if this is the case why do we need the `target` to populate the buffer and why is the signature of  `glBufferData` not:

```
void glBufferData(  GLint           bufferId,
                    GLsizeiptr      size,
                    const GLvoid *  data,
                    GLenum          usage);
```

Is that just a historical reason or because opengl is a statemachine or do I miss something and the `target` has an other purpose there.

Comment: the bufferID version is in the EXT_direct_state_access extension (core in 4.5) with the exact same signature though with name `glNamedBufferData(EXT)`

Comment: @ratchetfreak as  `glNamedBufferData` exists in 4.5 this indicates that my assumtion is right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common OpenGL API thing - most of the work with OpenGL objects (textures, buffers, ...) is done via binding them to a specific *target* and then using this *target* to refer to currently bound object (more on this [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Object)). Unfortunatelly, I do not know the exact reason for this, but it seems to appear historical now - I've seen some proposed extension for direct object access via object id's (UPD: user `ratchet freak` [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30530010/what-is-the-significance-of-the-target-argument-in-glbufferdata#comment49134509_30530010) that it is *direct_state_access* extension, core in 4.5).

The [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBindBuffer.xhtml) on **glBindBuffer** says that

> When a buffer object is bound to a target, the previous binding for that target is automatically broken.

I'd suppose that changing a buffer's binding type and expecting the buffer's state to stay preserved is not a good idea.

**UPDATE**

From [OpenGL wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object)

> The target​ defines how you intend to use this binding of the buffer object. When you're just creating and/or filling the buffer object with data, the target you use doesn't technically matter.

So, it seems that the target matters only on how you use the buffer, and you can safely bind it to any random type and fill it with data, but it still seems to be a bad practice.

Comment: Hmm, I bet I have read the page complelty, but I somehow did not see the `[...]the target you use doesn't technically matter.[...]`

Comment: About the `[...]I'd suppose that changing a buffer's binding type and expecting the buffer's state to stay preserved is not a good idea.[...]`  I don't think that this is a problem, as it is just about the binding of the buffer to the target and  wont effect the buffer and its content itself

Comment: @t.niese well, the driver could optimize something based on the target as it tells about intended buffer usage, and if these optimizations do not support changing of buffer's target, everything will go bad. But these are just thoughts, I have no concrete information on that.

Comment: That's what I also thought first. But I think your second quote it clear about that it should not matter when filling the buffer. And because `glNamedBufferData`  was added this (IMHO) shouldn't be a problem at all, because the driver needs to deal with this situation then anyway.

Comment: @t.niese sure, the second quote and the existence of this extension do clarify the situation.

Answer (score 0):

To use `glBufferData`, you need some way of indicating the target of the data you are uploading. The `target` parameter (the first one), lets this call know the destination for your data. If your only aim is to upload the data and then unbind, as you said, it doesn't really matter which buffer binding you use. You are free to bind that buffer to any other binding at a later time.

However, it quite common to setup vertex attributes during `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` data initialization time as well (with  `glVertexAttribPointer`/`glEnableVertexArray`), which might be another reason to use `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding over any other arbitrary binding. Also, if you intend to actually use the buffer data you are uploading in a subsequent draw call, and don't need to break the binding, it is more efficient to leave the binding in place.